# Await your command, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes
>
> Can't count the times that I've been used
>
> Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not
>
> But when I die, I won’t be forgot
>
> You hold of high authority, I bid your one command
>
> But of your money, I often demand
>
> As night draws near, I sit and wait
>
> For I'll be needed, when it's late.

What am I?

I don't think a hint is needed for this one.

Comment: are you a `vibrator`?

Comment: Was thinking of `hope`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are you

> A lightbulb

I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes

> Everyone knows that a good idea makes a light bulb appear above your head (a light bulb moment)

Can't count the times that I've been used

> Lots!

Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not

> Lamp shades!

But when I die, I wont be forgot

> A dead light bulb is a constant reminder that it's time to change the light bulb :)

You hold of high authority, I bid your one command

> On/Off

But of your money, I often demand

> Buy more, and pay electricity bills?

As night draws near, I sit and wait

> Pesky daylight stifles the need for light bulbs

For I'll be needed, when it's late.

> Until night time...

Comment: "Pesky daylight..." lol.

Comment: This was correct in every line!

Answer (score 3):

It could be only one thing:

> A software operations engineer on call.

I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes

> While they don't develop the software, they are an important part of the process

Can't count the times that I've been used

> Even the smallest problem in operations requires immense background knowledge, hence the operator is frequently pulled in to help

Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not

> Just a fact of the corporate world - sometimes your work is appreciated, other times the people who keep things running are invisible

But when I die, I wont be forgot

> "Hey, do you know how to do X? Jerry was always in charge of that, shame he was hit by a truck."

You hold of high authority, I bid your one command

> Operations engineers are often considered the 'body' of the company, while taking commands from the 'brain' (architects, tech leads, etc.)

But of your money, I often demand

> No one would want to do this s*** for free (except of course on evening, weekends, and holidays)

As night draws near, I sit and wait
For I'll be needed, when it's late.

> The operations engineer on call bitterly waits through the evening for production breaks at 1 AM.

Comment: Cool guess and nice reasons \++/

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A Hard Drive

I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes

> Hard drive stores information which is somewhat similar to an idea

Can't count the times that I've been used

> Hard Drives are used frequently.

Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not

> You can have external and internal hard drives, external ones can be seen and internal most times can't.

But when I die, I wont be forgot

> When a hard drive dies you often try and restore data from it so you don't often forget about it.

You hold of high authority, I bid your one command

> This can relate to hard drives in numerous ways. I think since data is written with ones and zeroes then it fits.

But of your money, I often demand

> You need to buy hard drives.

As night draws near, I sit and wait

> If you turn off your computer at night then the hard drive does nothing but sit and wait.

For I'll be needed, when it's late.

> Not sure if it matches this one, hard drives are often used at night.

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

> Law?

I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes:

> Laws are based on rules or *ideas* about rules.

Can't count the times that I've been used

> Law is formed/modified multiple times *(Example: added articles, chapters, etc)*.

Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not

> When a law is outdated or when is not such law *(after search in books).*

But when I die, I wont be forgot

> Law could be outdated, but it never dies *those laws remains in books?*.

You hold of high authority, I bid your one command

> Law is authority

But of your money, I often demand

> Maybe related to elections, needs money for make laws? *I'm not lawyer :p*

As night draws near, I sit and wait

> Not a single idea about that, honestly.

For I'll be needed, when it's late.

> Sometimes, when a terrible crime or similar situation occurs, a new law is created.

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be:

> Memory

I'm not an idea, but I stand in those shoes

> Idea and memory are both forms of thoughts. You think of an idea. You remember a memory.

Can't count the times that I've been used

> You can't really count the times you remember something/ have a memory.

Sometimes I'm seen, sometimes I'm not

> You can see recorded events in the future. They serve as memories. Like seeing a marriage video. And you can't actually see the memories that you just think of. Imagine maybe, but not actually see them.

But when I die, I wont be forgot

> You dont really forget a memory. Any memory might come fleeting by at any time.

You hold of high authority, I bid your one command

> Not sure about the hold of high authority. But you can remember certain events at your wish.

But of your money, I often demand

> You might want to create memories by recording events. Videotaping, clicking pictures etc. All of which require equipment that requires money.

As night draws near, I sit and wait

> You often think about your day before you go to sleep. Go by the day's memories.

For I'll be needed, when it's late.

> When someone dies, when they are 'late', all you have is their memories to cling on to.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the answer to this riddle is :

> Dream

Comment: Can you explain how this fits each clue / line? Answer's without explanation are likely to get deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Answers to riddles needs explanations for each clue, to prove why your idea works